# filling in the holes in the result of a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my query is returning:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
| Jan  | Feb  | Mar  | Apr  | May  | Jun  | Jul  |  Aug  | Sep  | Oct  | Nov  | Dec  | Bla |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    2 |    0 |  13 |
|    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    2 |    0 |    0 |  14 |
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    9 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    0 |    8 |   37 |  29 |
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |     0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |  374 |  30 |
|    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |   78 |    2 |    4 |     8 |   57 |  169 |  116 |  602 |  31 |
|  156 |  255 |   79 |   75 |  684 |  325 |  289 |   194 |  407 |  171 |  584 |  443 |  32 |
| 1561 | 2852 | 2056 |  796 | 2004 | 1755 |  879 |  1052 | 1490 | 1683 | 2532 | 2381 |  33 |
| 4167 | 3841 | 4798 | 3399 | 4132 | 5849 | 3157 |  4381 | 4424 | 4487 | 4178 | 5343 |  34 |
| 5472 | 5939 | 5768 | 4150 | 7483 | 6836 | 6346 |  6288 | 6850 | 7155 | 5706 | 5231 |  35 |
| 5749 | 4741 | 5264 | 4045 | 6544 | 7405 | 7524 |  6625 | 6344 | 5508 | 6513 | 3854 |  36 |
| 5464 | 6323 | 7074 | 4861 | 7244 | 6768 | 6632 |  7389 | 8077 | 8745 | 6738 | 5039 |  37 |
| 5731 | 7205 | 7476 | 5734 | 9103 | 9244 | 7339 |  8970 | 9726 | 9089 | 6328 | 5512 |  38 |
| 7262 | 6149 | 8231 | 6654 | 9886 | 9834 | 9306 | 10065 | 9983 | 9984 | 6738 | 5806 |  39 |
| 5886 | 6934 | 7137 | 6978 | 9034 | 9155 | 7389 |  9437 | 9711 | 8665 | 6593 | 5337 |  40 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

as you can see the BLA column starts from 13. i want it to start from 1, then 2, then 3 etc......I do not want any gaps in the data. The reason there are gaps is because all of the months are `0` for that specific `bla`

**how do i get the result set to include ALL values for `BLA`, even ones that will yield `0` for the months?**

here are the desired results:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Bla |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 2   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 3   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 4   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 5   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 6   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 7   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 8   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 9   |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 10  |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 11  |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 12  |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 13  |
| 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 2   | 0   | 0   | 14  |
| 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 15  |
| …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   | …   |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

here's my query:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN SUM(Jan) is not null THEN SUM(Jan) ELSE 0 end Jan,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Feb) is not null THEN SUM(Feb) ELSE 0 end Feb,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Mar) is not null THEN SUM(Mar) ELSE 0 end Mar,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Apr) is not null THEN SUM(Apr) ELSE 0 end Apr,
        CASE WHEN SUM(May) is not null THEN SUM(May) ELSE 0 end May,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Jun) is not null THEN SUM(Jun) ELSE 0 end Jun,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Jul) is not null THEN SUM(Jul) ELSE 0 end Jul,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Aug) is not null THEN SUM(Aug) ELSE 0 end Aug,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Sep) is not null THEN SUM(Sep) ELSE 0 end Sep,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Oct) is not null THEN SUM(Oct) ELSE 0 end Oct,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Nov) is not null THEN SUM(Nov) ELSE 0 end Nov,
        CASE WHEN SUM(Dec) is not null THEN SUM(Dec) ELSE 0 end Dec,
        CASE WHEN Bla > 191 THEN 192 ELSE Bla END Bla
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Bla > 191 THEN 192 ELSE Bla END
order by bla
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but instead of `CASE WHEN SUM(Jan) is not null THEN SUM(Jan) ELSE 0 end` you can write the more concise expression `ISNULL(SUM(Jan), 0)`.

Comment: How many values for `bla` are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a numbers table or some table that has all values from 1 to 192. You can create that table, make one on the go using a loop or a recursive CTE, using some of the system views, etc. This is one example:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Jan),0) Jan,
        ISNULL(SUM(Feb),0) Feb,
        ISNULL(SUM(Mar),0) Mar,
        ISNULL(SUM(Apr),0) Apr,
        ISNULL(SUM(May),0) May,
        ISNULL(SUM(Jun),0) Jun,
        ISNULL(SUM(Jul),0) Jul,
        ISNULL(SUM(Aug),0) Aug,
        ISNULL(SUM(Sep),0) Sep,
        ISNULL(SUM(Oct),0) Oct,
        ISNULL(SUM(Nov),0) Nov,
        ISNULL(SUM(Dec),0) Dec,
        A.RN Bla
FROM (  SELECT *, RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id)
        FROM sys.all_objects) A
LEFT JOIN CTE B
ON A.RN = CASE WHEN B.Bla > 191 THEN 192 ELSE B.Bla END
WHERE A.RN BETWEEN 1 AND 192
GROUP BY A.RN
order by A.RN
```

Comment: thank you so much! you have provided me with such amazing guidance and help! cachai?

Comment: lamak im sorry i slightly needed to change the query and your solution is not working for this for some reaosn

Comment: would you be so kind as to look at my query once more and see if there's a quick fix?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - Not really. I answered your question and that answer was valid an did what you asked for. Now you changed the question and unaccepted my answer, that's not appropiate behavior, you should've asked another question. I had already answered two of your questions, and now I know I won't be doing it again in the future

Comment: sorry to hear that. if i had asked another question it would have been closed as a duplicate so i didnt know the right way to proceed.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - This broaches the topic of knowing what you are asking. Take some time to think through your questions and use them as potential learning experiences and not one-off, symptomatic fixes.

Comment: @swasheck i totally agree with you

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов - I'm sorry to say this, and I don't mean any offense. But if you really think that your new question would be closed as a duplicate, then that's a symptom of your lack of an effort on adapting the answers you have at your dispossal. You should be able to use a modified version of the answer I had provided without the need to change the question.

Comment: i'm having trouble figuring out how to modify your answer to suite my new needs. thanks for any guidance or hints

Answer (score 1):

I created a demo of what might be what you need, it has several versions of Bla column, Bla3 is the final version displayed in result, you can easily modify this query to work on your table, try it:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Jan INT, Feb INT, Mar INT, Apr INT, May INT, Jun INT, 
Jul INT, Aug INT, Sep INT, Oct INT, Nov INT, Dec INT, Bla INT)
INSERT @tbl VALUES 
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12),
(0,12,10,10,10,11,10,0,0,0,0,21,35),
(0,12,10,10,10,11,10,0,0,0,0,22,47),
(0,12,10,10,10,11,10,0,0,0,0,23,192),
(0,12,10,10,10,11,10,0,0,0,0,24,203)

;WITH a AS (
    SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Bla) Bla2
    FROM @tbl
),
b AS (
    SELECT  *, 
            CASE WHEN Bla > 191 THEN 192 ELSE Bla2 END Bla3
    FROM a
)

SELECT  ISNULL(SUM(Jan), 0) Jan,
        ISNULL(SUM(Feb), 0) Feb,
        ISNULL(SUM(Mar), 0) Mar,
        ISNULL(SUM(Apr), 0) Apr,
        ISNULL(SUM(May), 0) May,
        ISNULL(SUM(Jun), 0) Jun,
        ISNULL(SUM(Jul), 0) Jul,
        ISNULL(SUM(Aug), 0) Aug,
        ISNULL(SUM(Sep), 0) Sep,
        ISNULL(SUM(Oct), 0) Oct,
        ISNULL(SUM(Nov), 0) Nov,
        ISNULL(SUM(Dec), 0) Dec,
        Bla3
FROM    b
GROUP   BY Bla3
ORDER   BY Bla3
```